# Embedding audio in a web page

Tags: html, audio, web

I'm currenlty desigining and building a website where I need to embed some audio files (some 60sec extracts from various tracks from a band's album) so people can listen to their material quickly without having to download any files to their desktop etc.

I know QuickTime was a favourite in the past (perhaps it still is?) but I've had some experience with lag and poor load times of a web page because of this. Also, I understand there's an  tag in HTML5 but I wonder about compatibility?

Really I just wondered if anyone had any recommendations on the a tried and tested approach to accomplish this?

Comment: HTML5 is more media-friendly that previous versions, but the W3C didn't specify any default standard codecs for video OR audio, so while the browser knows that it's got a video or audio file, it still must use external apps/plugins to actually PLAY that media file. MP3 is still patent encumbered, so direct browser support isn't likely until those patents expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an ideal solution, but I went for a Flash based plugin in the end - seems to work resonably well on compatible devices (shame it's not particularly well supported on mobiles/tablets etc. though).

Give 'dewplayer' a Google if you're interested...